# 2.8x ADD-ON - I need an add-on to "paint" instances of an object over another object's surface

Tags: add-on, instances

In 2.79 I used to use an add-on called "Paint Clones" which would allow me to basically paint instances of one or more objects over another object's surface with random scale/rotation.

That add-on hasn't been updated for Blender 2.8x, which means I need a substitute.
I've googled far and wide, but the only similar tool I've found died with Blender 2.79 as well.

Obviously I've tried resorting to particle systems but, besides the useless intricacies of setting them up, they don't allow me to place multiple/different objects with a single system, nor (seemingly) to randomize rotation over multiple axes.

Does anybody know of an unspoken Blender function or add-on that could help me in the task?

Comment: "paint" vertex groups and use instanced objects as hair.

Comment: @Timaroberts sorry, I dont understand what you mean. Or, rather, I have a doubt you didnt read my request.
Please, read again, especially the part about particle systems not being functional for my puposes because of their several limitations.

Comment: I’ll try to write up a full answer a bit later today, but in short, weight painting creates a vertex group to use for hair density and a new collection (your clone object) will instance hair.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what your goal is correctly, then here is a solution that should work for you in version 2.8 without needing any add-ons or extra tools.

Move your clone object(s) to a new collection with <kbd>M</kbd> and give it(them) a useful name, such as "hair".

Add a new vertex group to your main object, Suzanne in our example here. You can leave it at the default name "group" or rename it to something more useful like "hair".

[Add a new particle system](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/particle_system_panel.html#creating-a-particle-system) and change the following settings to begin with:

[image]

Most default settings are usually fine, but here you want to [*Render as Collection*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/emitter/render.html#collection), and set the [*Density Vertex Group*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/emitter/vertex_groups.html#vertex-groups)

With all of that done, you can now paint your clones. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> into *[Weight Paint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/weight_paint/index.html#weight-paint) Mode*  and  paint away! Everything will paint into the last active vertex group, adding to the density group of your hair system.<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> again to return to *object mode*

See the gif below adding icospheres to Suzanne.

[image]

You may also [randomize velocity](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/emitter/velocity.html#velocity) if you'd like, (this will allow some randomness in rotations)  the option is pictured below.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't answer my question, but it sure helps. Does the "randomize" parameter affect all the axes or only one?
Anyway, the selling point of the add-on I used in 2.79 was its simplicity and flexibility. All I had to do was select some objects and acquire them as the source, then select the target and set scale/rotation variations for each axis separately, plus a radius for the density.
Simple, functional, flexible, straight to the point.